# How to get values for a jquery ajax post requst on a nodejs server

Tags: jquery, node.js, express

I want to get values sent via jquery post request. I want to achieve this using nodejs and express or body parser module if possible.

### Jquery code

```
$(window).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var url = $(location).attr('href'); // url = /home
        $.post(url, { pageInfo : 'simple jquery post request' }, function(data, status) {
            alert('data: ' + data + '\nStatus: ' + status);
        });
    }, 1000)
});
```

### Nodejs and express code

```
router.post('/:id', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.pageInfo); // using body-parser module/middleware
    // to show data in the console posted by the jqyery ajax post request
    // it is returning 'undefined'

    res.send('info received');
})
```

Comment: Hi, whats the issue? Code seems to be fine. Only need to add the parser middleware to app instance of express - app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false })); in your main server.js file

Comment: Hey, I have done anything necessary for those middlewares to work in the server.js file. The body parser is working fine for any other post requests especially those requests sent using an html form.

Comment: Can you send the ajax request showing in the browser developer tool?

Comment: Yes, I can see the form data in the developer tools (network) XHR etc

Comment: Great can you please send https://pastebin.com/ link for your main server file?

Comment: That website is new to me. whats the deal. tell me what I should do on that website then I`ll try fixing the bug some other time so I can get comfortable with it first before I use it to help fix my problem.

Comment: You just need to copy you code and paste it in above website. It will generate a link, copy that link and share it here will look into your code.

Comment: ok got it. https://pastebin.com/39xPfcwH that`s the link

Comment: Can you check server js file code - https://pastebin.com/xTifALbG

Comment: I have now fixed the problem. thanks for the help.

Comment: What was the issue?